# How to split single line into multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, onclick, line

I've recently been looking into how to split a single line into multiple lines using D3. This will be when the user clicks the single line which will then split on click. I can't find any examples online on how to do this. Can someone let me know if this is possible? Thank you in advance!

**D3:**

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        if(d.value < 76742302){
          return 1;
        }else if(d.value < 159879796){
          return 2;
        }else if (d.value < 354232554) {
          return 3;
        }else if (d.value < 695427312) {
          return 4;
        }else{
          return 5;
        }
      });
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Some code?

Comment: What do you want to split on?

Comment: Yes sorry, my lines currently are sized based on value's coming in from a JSON file

Comment: You mean split a line when click on it to 2 connected lines or to 2  draggable  lines?

Comment: there will be a fixed line. When you click on that line it splits off into 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

'svg:line' usually have x1, y1, x2, y2 values.

You can use some basic algebra to calculate the line equation (http://www.coolmath.com/algebra/08-lines/12-finding-equation-two-points-01)

and find the point where you want to split the line and create two new line elements.

if you want to split it half way just find the mid point x1 + x2 / 2 and y1 + y2 / 2 and create two new lines and append them to the parent and remove the current.

```
on click
add new line from start to mid
add new line from mid to end
remove self
```